# Combinatorics: Distributing tasks in class

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose you sit in a class room with $n$ students. There are $k$ question and every student can pick $5$ of them. How many different ways are there such that no question is left out?

In total we have $5\cdot n$ decisions. This is a really hard question, I tried simulating some cases but I don't see a common pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $\binom{k}5$ different sets of $5$ questions, so there are $\binom{k}5^n$ different ways for each of $n$ students to choose a set of $5$ questions. From this figure we need to subtract the number of ways that leave out at least one question. For any question $Q$ there are $\binom{k-1}5$ sets of $5$ questions that do not include $Q$, so $\binom{k-1}5^n$ of the $\binom{k}5^n$ ways leave out $Q$. Since there are $k$ questions, this might suggest that the answer is $$\binom{k}5^n-k\binom{k-1}5^n\,,\tag{1}$$ but that fails to take into account the fact that every combination of choices that leaves out **two** questions has been subtracted twice, once for each of the omitted questions, and is therefore counted $-1$ times in $(1)$. There are $\binom{k}2$ pairs of questions, and there are $\binom{k-2}5^n$ ways for the class to leave out a specific pair of questions, so in $(1)$ we’ve subtracted $\binom{k}2\binom{k-2}5^n$ too much; restoring it gives us

$$\binom{k}5^n-k\binom{k-1}5^n+\binom{k}2\binom{k-2}5^n\,.\tag{2}$$

We’re not done, since any set of class choices that leaves out three questions is counted $1-3+3=1$ time in $(2)$, and it shouldn’t be counted at all. Can you complete the inclusion-exclusion calculation from here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I have to continue this pattern until I leave out $k-5$ tasks? That is the most extreme case, namely that every students picks the same five questions? Is that a sum from $k=1$ to $k-5$?

Comment: @Analysis: It’s actually a sum from $i=0$ to $i=k-5$: you need $i=0$ to get the $\binom{k}5^n$ term. You don’t actually have to give the upper limit, though: you can take $\sum_{i\ge 0}$, since only finitely many terms are non-zero: $\binom{k-i}5=0$ when $i>k-5$.

Comment: So, we basically have: $$\sum \limits_{j=0}^{k-5}(-1)^j\begin{pmatrix} k\\j \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} k-j\\5 \end{pmatrix}^n$$

Comment: @Analysis: That’s what I get, and I don’t at the moment see any simplification.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So the probability that the students, each with $5$ picks, as a class pick all $k$ tasks is $$P=\frac{\sum \limits_{j=0}^{k-5}(-1)^j\begin{pmatrix} k\\j \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} k-j\\5 \end{pmatrix}^n}{\begin{pmatrix} k\\5 \end{pmatrix}^n}$$ where we have $n$ students, $k$ tasks and $5$ picks for each student.

Comment: @Analysis After examining https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle I subsequently realized the backbone of the idea is that if an element is in $k$ regions, it will be enumerated as $\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{(k-1)}\binom{k}{i}$ times.  Binomial expansion on $(1 + [-1])^k$ indicates that this enumeration $= 1.$

Comment: @Analysis: Yes, that converts that raw number to the desired probability.

Comment: Is it possible to interpret it like this: We have $5n$ choices in total, hereinafter we will interpret "choices" as balls and the $k$ tasks as boxes. How many ways are there to distribute $5n$ balls into $k$ boxes such that no box is left out?

Comment: @Analysis: No, because that doesn’t take into account the fact that each student picks exactly $5$ questions: it loses the association of questions with students. We actually have $5$ balls labelled $1$, $5$ balls labelled $2$, and so on up to $5$ balls labelled $n$.

Comment: ah yeah, you're right.